# unable to parse xlsx with Spreadsheet::Read

Tags: perl, file, spreadsheet, cpan

I am Trying to parse a **.xlsx** file using **[Spreadsheet::Read](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm)** same code works for **.xls** files but throws an error **.xlsx** below is procedure followed:

1. We are creating a file upload(browse) button in **.cgi** file with name **"csv_path"**.
2. when user submits the form (of course its *multipart/form-data*)
3. code on next page

   ```
   use CGI;
   use Spreadsheet::Read;
   use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
   use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

   #will catch uploaded file.
   my $fname = $query->param("csv_path");

   print Dumper($fname); 
   #just for confirmation we printed variable $fname
   #when .xls is uploaded $fname contains:
   #$VAR1 = bless( \*{'Fh::fh00001308_4_template.xls'}, 'Fh' );
   #when .xlsx is uploaded $fname contains:
   #$VAR1 = bless( \*{'Fh::fh00001308_4_template.xlsx'}, 'Fh' );

   #now read the file with "Spreadsheet::Read"
   my $data_xls  = ReadData ( $fname, "strip"=>3, "dtfmt" => "mm/dd/yyyy");#here if we pass .xlsx file name(stored on server) to ReadData() it works properly.


   #print out of Spreadsheet::Read
   print "<pre>";
   print Dumper($data_xls);

   #when .xls is uploaded $data_xls comes up with all required data

   #when .xlsx is uploaded below error occurs
   #   XLSX parser cannot parse data: Undefined subroutine Fh::opened
   ```

Please suggest if any changes required or any thing missing.

Comment: use [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) for parseing xlsx files

Comment: already there is code written for .xls parsing using "Spreadsheet::Read", i just want to enhance the same for .xlsx files, if using Spreadsheet::XLSX wont required any change in code then its ok for me.[also i dont have Spreadsheet::XLSX installed and no access for installations either]

Comment: ok, but if we pass the .xlsx file stored on server to same function it returns the proper out. i guess there is some problem with stream data (bless( \*{'Fh::fh00001308_4_template.xls'}, 'Fh' )) here.

Comment: Try the module: `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX`.

Comment: @simbabque - The docs for [Spreadsheet::Read](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read) indicate that it's basically a wrapper around several spreadsheet parsing modules, including several for XLSX.

Answer (score 1):

Here instead of passing stream data directly we are suppose to store the file at temporary location, and then pass the file name with location to the ReadData() function.
Please refer below code:

```
use CGI;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $corrected_filename = $query->param('csv_path');
$corrected_filename =~ s/ /_/g;
# $corrected_filename .= "$username";
#store file locally
local $| = 1;
my ($bytesread,$buffer,$file);
my $fh = $query->upload('csv_path');
open(OUTF, '>' . "/tmp/upload-".$corrected_filename);
while ($bytesread = read($fh, $buffer, 1024)) {
    print(OUTF $buffer);
}
close(OUTF);
my $data_xls  = ReadData ("/tmp/upload-".$corrected_filename, "strip"=>3, "dtfmt" => "mm/dd/yyyy");#here if we pass .xlsx file name(stored on server) to ReadData() it works properly.


#print out of Spreadsheet::Read
print "<pre>";
print Dumper($data_xls);
```

And  when code read finish we can unlink the file.